# campo input código de barra, (Ejecucion de consulta) VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**Buenas a todos en la comunidad saludos de antemano,** tengo el siguiente problema que quiero solventar en una aplicación hecha en Laravel con VueJS.

Presento el siguiente codigo en VueJS

```
checkout(query){
                var vm = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                     axios.post('/api/search/producto-venta', {term: query})
                         .then(response => {
                             console.log(response.data.data)
                             vm.add_product = response.data.data
                             vm.buscar_producto = '';
                         })
                }, 3000);
            },
```

El siguiente código realiza una búsqueda de un código de barra cuando este es insertado en este campo input.

```
 <input v-if="type == true" type="text" id="buscar_producto" v-model="buscar_producto"  placeholder="Busque un producto aqui..."
                   class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase;"
                   onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" @input="checkout(buscar_producto)">
```

Esto se hace mediante un lector de codigos de barras el problema es que el codigo de barra inserta los caracteres numericos que conforman el codigo de barra uno por uno los va insertando de manera rápida haciendo que mi consulta se haga de hasta 5 o 6 veces el cual esta hace varias búsquedas que inserta las cantidad de productos por busquedas sin hace 3 consultas son en cantidad 3 productos, asi como se muestra en la imagen 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] 
Lo que pido es que si hay una manera de que cuando el código de barra inserte todo el código este en cuestión de segundo detecte que ya no hay un evento escrito en el campo input y pase a realizar una sola consulta y no varias al mismo tiempo. claro todo esto en vue js pero no sabría como empezar o si hay algún ejemplo de como hacer este tipo de requerimiento que se necesita

Answer (score 0):

Puedes limpiar el setTimeout con clearTimeout antes de asignarlo nuevamente y si aún no se ejecutó, es decír, algo así.

```
checkout(query){
   var vm = this;
   if(vm.timeout_function != false){
       clearTimeout(vm.timeout_function);
   }
   vm.timeout_function = setTimeout(function() {
   axios.post('/api/search/producto-venta', {term: query})
           .then(response => {
               console.log(response.data.data)
               vm.add_product = response.data.data
               vm.buscar_producto = '';
               clearTimeout(vm.timeout_function);
            })
   }, 3000);
},
```